# what is wrong with my code it sayed that invalid combination of opcode and operand

Tags: assembly, nasm

here is my code

```
    [ORG 0x0100]
    
    jmp  start
    
    even: dw 16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32    
    avg:  dw 0
    
average:     
a1: add  ax, [bx]    
    add  bx, 2    
    loop a1    
    ret
    
start:    
    mov ax,0    
    mov bx,even    
    mov cx,8    
    call average    
    mov bx,9    
    div ax    
    mov avg,ax    
    mov ax, 0x4c00  ;terminate program    
    int 0x21
```

I do not know why I am getting this error.

Comment: It didn't tell you what line had the error?

Comment: What assembler are you programming for?  If this is NASM, you need to write `mov [avg], ax`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> invalid combination of opcode and operand

If this is **N**ASM, then `mov avg,ax` needs to become `mov [avg], ax` to avoid the error.
If this were **M**ASM, then `mov bx,even` needs to become `mov bx, OFFSET even` for correct results.

You got errors!

- The array has 9 elements but you process only 8 with `mov cx,8`.
- Eventhough you prepare for a division by 9 with `mov bx,9`, you execute `div ax` which is wrong.
- The word-sized division requires zeroing DX beforehand

```
start:    
    mov ax, 0    
    mov bx, even    
    mov cx, 9    
    call average    
    mov bx, 9
    xor dx, dx    
    div bx
    mov [avg], ax    
    mov ax, 0x4C00  ;terminate program    
    int 0x21
```

Comment: Instead of hard-coding `8` or `9`, do `.len equ ($ - even)/2` right after defining `even`.  Then `mov cx, even.len`.  That gets the assembler to calculate the size for you, as an assemble-time constant you can use as an immediate later.